# htaccess , htpasswd and error 401

Tags: htaccess, authentication, htpasswd

I have a problem with htpasswd.

I get an error in error.log apache2

> user admin: authentication failure for "/": Password Mismatch

Content of my htaccess file:

```
# Set Access Restrictions

AuthType Basic
AuthName "admin"
AuthUserFile ".htpasswd"
require valid-user
```

and content of my htpasswd

```
admin:xxxxx
```

Comment: What did you use to generate your .htpasswd file?

Comment: with notepad++  and I changed the name ...there is another software ??

Comment: See this page: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htpasswd.html It my be that you did not edit the file correctly. As well, passwords **must** be 8 characters. There are also limitations with .htpasswd on Apache on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

From your comment I take it that you just created a plain text password. This will not work for Apache, as Apache expects the password in .htpasswd to be hashed by the MD5 algorithm.

There are several tools available online for generating .htpasswd files, but the easiest might be the one that comes with Apache, it's called `htpasswd`. On RHEL (Fedora, Red Hat, CentOS) systems you'll need the *httpd-tools* package (`yum install httpd-tools`). On Ubuntu systems it's in the *apache2-utils* package (`apt-get install apache2-utils`). If you're using XAMPP on Windows it's in the folder xampp\apache\bin.

To use htpasswd with the .htaccess file you've already got configured, you'd simply do `htpasswd /protected/.htpasswd user` and then type in your desired password (twice) when prompted. It will then generate your .htpasswd file in the /protected/ directory.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are including the entire path for `AuthUserFile`. I would suggest that you create a `protected` directory instead of doing this on the root directory. I made sure and tested these configurations to ensure that they worked.

#### File Locations

```
/protected/.htaccess
/protected/.htpasswd
```

#### .htaccess File

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /protected/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

#### . htpasswd File

```
user:password
```

Make sure that the password is MD5'd, here is a [tool](http://davidwalsh.name/web-development-tools).

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have not hash a password to md5 .... I've used notepad ++ and I put the password in simple character

I followed this tutorial with the linux command for create file htaccess

[image]

now my content of my htpasswd :

```
admin:$apr1$Oy4JMDb0$yb00PbzV9mrq07lPivrzL1
```